# Problemas com o resultado Curl e file_get_contents

Tags: php, html, libcurl, file-get-contents

Estou tentando pegar uma imagem de um site para usar o imagecreatefrompng(), porém o resutado nunca foi oque esperava...

Url: https://www.habbo.com.br/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?user=vfr&direction=3&size=m no caso quando chamo como `<img>` funciona perfeitamente

```html
<img src="https://www.habbo.com.br/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?user=vfr&direction=3&size=m">
```

o problema é que quando chamo em curl retorna isto:

> GIF89a6>����XXXLLL555AAAFFF)))///_t#4�ه* íl��Q�Ђ!� (c)
>   sulake!�,6>�H����*\Ȱ�Ç#J�H��ŋ3j�ȱ�Ǐ C�I��ɓ(S�\��J�-c
>   �ʘ��I��͓(P�@ѣpI2���D�"M�Td˧�5ʵ(��?=�Ukׯh�vp�@۶e�"E@�n،l���@ݝ<�^d�voٿ�w�L����"HLy�b��
>   ?�[9q��   j~�����:AӤ��qD�o9���Z&��!�>p�3m�(`;3�CؓoS�s��3�H8�e��[.����t����߾�]�s�������4[
>   ��`�̘��z ~���5 \�@�k��_L < `��7�~��t`�*aKV�
>   nx�}!��#�h�B�b�   .��0�`~@`8�H!�JĖh>J
>   ��/ӎ�g�&�4a�� )�7�!�/�$�Ӆ)�Kh���l���p�)�tB;

ja tentei usar file_get_contents mas é uma url https e não funciona, quero que retorne a imagem para poder usar com imagecreatefrompng() do php

código que utilizei:

```php
function getimg($url) {
    $headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';
    $headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';

    $process = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch'));
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    $return = curl_exec($process);
    curl_close($process);

    return $return;
}

echo getimg('https://www.habbo.com.br/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?user=vfr&direction=3&size=m');

//echo '<img src="'.getimg('https://www.habbo.com.br/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?user=vfr&direction=3&size=m').'">';
//$habbo = imagecreatefrompng('https://www.habbo.com.br/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?user=vfr&direction=3&size=m');
//imagecopy($im, $habbo, -2, -9, 0, 0, 33, 33);
```

Comment: Cara passo estar errado, mas o `Content-Type:`não deveria ser `image/jpeg` ?

Comment: Oh... parece que se vc habilitar no seu `php.ini` o `extension=php_openssl.dll` e `allow_url_fopen = On`, você poderá usar `file_get_content`... Sei lá são só ideias...

Comment: Tentou algo como `header('Content-type: image/png');` por exemplo, para saber se a imagem é _montada_? O `$process = curl_init($url);` pode ser `$process = curl_init();` no seu caso, já que você definiu a url usando o `CURLOPT_URL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acabei de testar aqui com sucesso[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]:

Na realidade consegue ser mais simples do que o que estavas a fazer:

```
function getimg($url) {
    $process = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    $return = curl_exec($process);
    curl_close($process) ;
    return $return;
}

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo getimg('https://www.habbo.com.br/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?user=vfr&direction=3&size=m');
```

Aqui uma solução com file_get_contents():

```
function getimg($url) {
    $options = array(
        'http'=>array(
            'method'=> "GET",
            'header'=> "Accept-language: en\r\n" .
            'User-Agent: ' .$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']. "\r\n"
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    return file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
}
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo getimg('https://www.habbo.com.br/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?user=vfr&direction=3&size=m');
```

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda! a curl não retornou nada, porem o file_get_contents() funcionou perteitamente. Obrigado!

Comment: O curl não retornou? Estranho, como podes ver pela imagem resultou no meu também @LeandroFerreira

Comment: http://image.prntscr.com/image/1cdabad1221c412aa873b10731c24990.png  achei estranho também @Miguel

Comment: @LeandroFerreira, experimenta tirar o `header('content....)` a ver se te aparece algum erro sff, ou experimenta acrescentar `curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);` tal como tenho na imagem

Comment: testei as duas alternativas, ambas não retornaram, tentei alterar o header (gif,jpeg,png...), ultilizei um or die e teve este retorno http://image.prntscr.com/image/f0be091e9b134a0b8dd39f7bd4ef06d0.png, @Miguel

Comment: Não faço ideia o que possa ser, mas se tirares os "die()" não retorna qualquer erro? Tens os erros habilitados @LeandroFerreira

Comment: Irei testar em outros servidores, como funciona no seu, não tenho duvidas que o código seja funcional!. http://image.prntscr.com/image/718e151b55ab4afb8e9a543c0a163fad.png @Miguel

Comment: ): entretanto se descobrires o que era vem aqui dizer sff @LeandroFerreira , mas ainda bem que o `file_get_contents()` resulta

Comment: Ok. Se eu descobrir irei voltar. Agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Você pose usar o seguinte código, que faz uso do [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) ao invés do `curl`, nele é passado o `User-Agent` para que a conexão não seja rejeitada, também é feita a captura do `mime-type` automaticamente através da função [`finfo`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.fileinfo.php).

Para que não ocorra erros na obtenção do `mime-type`, verifique no `php.ini` se a dll do *fileinfo* está habilitada `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` sem o `;`.

```
function getimg($url) {
$options = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:40.0) Gecko/40.0 Firefox/40.0
\r\n" // Edite com o user agent que você deseja usar
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$image = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

//Obtem o Mime Type
$file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime_type = $file_info->buffer($image);

return 'data:'.$mime_type.';base64,'.base64_encode($image);
} 

echo '<img src="'.getimg('https://www.habbo.com.br/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?user=vfr&direction=3&size=m').'">';
```

Com isso você poderá fazer uso do `<img src=` para utilizar as imagens diretamente no código sem a necessidade do uso do `header`.